# How to choose array [0] and make it a link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array, but I would like to go to a different URL when `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Hotel Selection</a>` is clicked. Here is what I have so far. Thanks for the help.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="left-edges inactive"></li>
        <li class="inactive" style="width: 149px;">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)">Hotel Selection</a>
        </li>
        <li class="seperator"></li>
        <li class="inactive" style="width: 124px;"></li>
        <li class="seperator"></li>
        <li class="inactive" style="width: 170px;"></li>
        <li class="seperator"></li>
        <li class="active" style="width: 134px;"></li>
        <li class="seperator"></li>
        <li class="inactive" style="width: 71px;"></li>
        <li class="seperator"></li>
        <li class="inactive" style="width: 95px;"></li>
        <li class="right-edges inactive"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$ (document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').click(function(){

        var x = document.getElementById("menu").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("menu").options;

        if (y[x].index == "0") {
            window.location.href='https://google.com';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the values of `x` and `y` right before the `if` statement?

Comment: I was trying to use x and y for the array. x for array index number and y for array name

Comment: Your menu is not a `select` box, therefore it has no `selectedIndex` nor `options` properties.

Comment: got it. so can you point me in the right direction? leaving the html as it is, how can I click "Hotel selection" and go to a URL?

Comment: `<a href="https://google.com">Hotel Selection</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following statements are incorrect, they return undefined.

```
var x = document.getElementById("menu").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("menu").options;
```

Try the following. Set your event listener on the hyperlink, then redirect it when whatever conditions are satisfied.

```
$ (document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li a').click(function(){

        var href =$(this).attr('href');

        if (href.indexOf('Javascript')>=0) {
            alert('https://google.com');
            //window.location.href='https://google.com';
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dshun/34fhL30s/27/